# Finding rows that have the minimum of a specific factor group

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm am attempting to find the minimum incomes from the state.x77 dataset based on the state.region variable.

```
df1 <- data.frame(state.region,state.x77,row.names = state.name)
tapply(state.x77,state.region,min)
```

I am trying to get it to output which state has the lowest income for X region eg for south Alabama would be the lowest income. Im trying to use tapply but I keep getting an error saying

```
Error in tapply(state.x77, state.region, min) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution. First get the vector of incomes and make of it a named vector. Then use `tapply` to get the names of the minima incomes.

```
state <- setNames(state.x77[, "Income"], rownames(state.x77))
tapply(state, state.region, function(x) names(x)[which.min(x)])
#     Northeast          South  North Central           West 
#       "Maine"  "Mississippi" "South Dakota"   "New Mexico"
```

---

The following, more complicated, code will output state names, regions and incomes.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  State = rownames(state.x77),
  Income = state.x77[, "Income"],
  Region = state.region
)
merge(aggregate(Income ~ Region, df1, min), df1)[c(3, 1, 2)]
#         State        Region Income
#1 South Dakota North Central   4167
#2        Maine     Northeast   3694
#3  Mississippi         South   3098
#4   New Mexico          West   3601
```

---

And another solution with `aggregate` but avoiding `merge`.

```
agg <- aggregate(Income ~ Region, df1, min)
i <- match(agg$Income, df1$Income)
data.frame(
  State = df1$State[i],
  Region = df1$Region[i],
  Income = df1$Income[i]
)
#         State        Region Income
#1        Maine     Northeast   3694
#2  Mississippi         South   3098
#3 South Dakota North Central   4167
#4   New Mexico          West   3601
```

Comment: Works perfectly, how would I Display the value of income as well? I was thinking of creating a data frame with the columns being state.region,state and then the income amount

Comment: Ok, I see thank you so much. Are there any other ways of accomplishing this without using merge or aggregate just out of curiosity?

Comment: @JDkreyfelt The aggregation is by region so only region and income are in the result.

Comment: @JDkreyfelt This last edit avoids `merge`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

state2 %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  bind_cols(state.region) %>%
  rename(State = rowname,
         Region = ...10) %>%
  group_by(Region, State) %>%
  summarise(Income = sum(Income)) %>% arrange(desc(Income)) %>% 
  slice_tail(n = 1)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Region [4]
  Region        State        Income
  <fct>         <chr>         <dbl>
1 Northeast     Maine          3694
2 South         Mississippi    3098
3 North Central South Dakota   4167
4 West          New Mexico     3601
```